# Re-activated: How do you disable a DataGridView's keyboard shorcuts?

Tags: datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, copy-paste

This issue is same as [2619535](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619535/how-do-you-disable-a-datagridviews-keyboard-shorcuts).

The given solution is working fine for me if there are no other keyboard events.
Unfortunately it is breaking copy/paste events from keyboard.
How to keep Ctrl + c and Ctrl +v functionality intact with this. I am not able to use these shortcuts for copy/paste.

Please assist.

Thanks in advance.
Vijay

Comment: You can use ListView instead of Datagrid to avoid copying and pasting data.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. But it's difficult to change the control at this point of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for not copying the data

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    Clipboard.Clear()
End Sub
```

and you can set the datagridview into readonly properties to avoid pasting data on datagrid

Comment: I want to keep existing Copy/Paste functionality. Along with the new addition for ctrl + h.